# C++ template specialisation & inheritance

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang++

I have a following piece of code, which should declare base struct and then declare template struct inheriting from it. Then the struct is partially specilised.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<class A, class B>
struct Parent {
    std::pair<A, B> m_pair;
    void print() {
        std::cout << m_pair.first << ", " << m_pair.second << "\n";
    }
};

template <class A, class B>
struct Some : public Parent<A, B> {
    Some(A a, B b) : Parent<A, B>({ {a, b} }) {}
    void add() {
        m_pair.first += m_pair.second;
    }
};

template <class B>
struct Some<B, float> : public Parent<B, float> {
    Some(B a, float b) : Parent<B, float>({ {a, b} }) {}
    void add() {
        m_pair.first -= m_pair.second;
    }
};

int main() {
    Some<int, float> s(4, 42);
    s.add(); 
    s.print();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it in Visual Studio 2015, everything compiles just fine and works as expected. However when I compile with GCC 5.2.1 or clang 3.6 I get following error:

```
untitled.cpp: In member function ‘void Some<A, B>::add()’:
untitled.cpp:17:9: error: ‘m_pair’ was not declared in this scope  
         m_pair.first += m_pair.second;  
         ^
untitled.cpp: In member function ‘void Some<B, float>::add()’:
untitled.cpp:24:9: error: ‘m_pair’ was not declared in this scope
         m_pair.first += m_pair.second;
```

What's wrong? However when I refer  `m_pair` as `Parent<A, B>::m_pair` it works in GCC and clang.

What is the correct way to define specilised template clasess (with specilised methods), which share common methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the base class is dependent on template parameters, the base members are not examined during unqualified name lookup.

Fortunately the fix is easy: just prefix the base member accesses with `this->`:

```
this->m_pair.first += this->m_pair.second;
this->m_pair.first -= this->m_pair.second;
```

This *will* look in the base class, so the member will be found.

The unqualified lookup works in MSVC because that compiler is non-conformant in many aspects of its template implementation.